# Read binary from avro files using Spark 1.6

Tags: scala, apache-spark, binary, avro

I'm trying to extract data from avro files using Spark 1.6.2 but one of the fields is BinaryType and I cannot find a way to decode it.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

val data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("plant/topics/1237/raw-data+0+0217766569+0217826453+1237+3805+1478076745829.avro")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [PLANT: string, MACHINE: string, DATA_TYPE: string, TIMESTAMP: bigint, EMITTER: string, API: string, PAYLOAD: binary, SIZE: bigint, CONTENT_TYPE: string, APP: string, PART: int, PARTS: int, DATA_MODE: string, SYSTEM_VERSION: string, FORMAT_VERSION: string, DATA_COUNT: int]
```

PAYLOAD is my binary column but even using an other method I can't seem to be able to decode it.

```
val struct = StructType(StructField("PAYLOAD", BinaryType, true) :: Nil)
struct: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(PAYLOAD,BinaryType,true))

val data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").schema(struct).load("plant/topics/1237/raw-data+0+0217766569+0217826453+1237+3805+1478076745829.avro")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [PAYLOAD: binary]
```

Help would be very much appreciated !